# Remove ipython widget from box (previously container widget)

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook, hbox

I am trying to remove a child widget from an HBox ipython widget group within an ipython notebook. Creating the widget group looks like this:

```
    buttons = [widgets.Button(description=str(i)) for i in range(5)]
    mybox = widgets.HBox(children=buttons)
    mybox
```

This displays 5 buttons.

Now I have a group of five buttons and I would like to remove the last button. As far as I can tell the box object does not have a method to remove children. So my thought was to close the last widget in the group:

```
    mybox.children[-1].close()
```

Now, only the first 4 buttons are displayed (0, 1, 2, 3) which is what I want, however if I get the description from the group the 5th button is still there:

```
    [child.description for child in mybox.children]

    ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

The output I expected, and what I need is this:

```
   ['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

I can simply create a copy of a slice, however this causes other problems, and I would really like to be able to modify the original  box.

This is *not* what I need:

```
    mybox = widgets.HBox(children=mybox.children[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I have been able to figure out after working on this is:

```
remove = mybox.children[-1]
mybox.children = mybox.children[:-1]
remove.close()
```

This is not perfect, but does work. Hopefully it will help anyone else with a similar problem.